# Printing Json file in HTML via Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, cordova

I am in the early stages of creating a phonegap project and converting it to iOS. I am on my second page of HTML and I'm having problems printing a Json file in the HTML. After trying countless different js methods I feel like it is not even importing the Json file at all. I even tried moving the Json file into the same directory and still I am getting nothing. I then tried a simple js method to print a piece of Json within the HTML and this still did not work (regardless of what .html file I used it in).

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
                    var newObj = {
                        "Chapter" : "1",
                        "Name" : "Tests"
                    }
                    console.log (newObj.Chapter)
            </script>
```

This is this original js function a was using to import and print the Json

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {


 var contents = [];
 var imp = "contents.json"
  $.getJSON(imp, function(data) {
     $.each(data.tcontent, function(index, item) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + item.Chapter + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Name + "</td>" + "</tr>"
         $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
    });

 });

}); 
</script>
```

And this is the Json I am trying to import (contents.json)

```
{"tcontent" : [
{"Chapter" : "1", "Name" : "Introduction & Contact Details" },
{"Chapter" : "2", "Name" : "General Principles of Antibiotic Perscribing" },
{"Chapter" : "3", "Name" : "Note on meticillin resistant SA"},
 ]
}
```

I have imported a javascript library into the html, I've id of the table in the html is userdata etc, I just have no idea why it won't work.
Any light you could shed on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Your Json was not well formed, I removed "," from last object

{
  "tcontent": [{
    "Chapter": "1",
    "Name": "Introduction & Contact Details"
  }, {
    "Chapter": "2",
    "Name": "General Principles of Antibiotic Perscribing"
  }, {
    "Chapter": "3",
    "Name": "Note on meticillin resistant SA"
  }]
}

var imp = "contents.json"
 $.getJSON(imp, function(data) {
    var tblRow = "";
     $.each(data.tcontent, function(index, item) {
         tblRow += "<tr>" + "<td>" + item.Chapter + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.Name + "</td>" + "</tr>"

    });
     $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     //alert(tblRow)
 });
```